# random .ts filenames in the m3u8 file

Tags: video, ffmpeg, video-streaming, html5-video

Hi guys my ffmpeg line currently looks like this

```
ffmpeg -i "http://x.com/x.ts" -s 810x520 -pix_fmt yuv420p -vcodec copy -acodec copy -bsf:v h264_mp4toannexb -preset baseline  -strict -2 -flags -global_header -f segment -segment_list "E:\2.m3u8"  -segment_time 10 -segment_list_size 5 "E:\2-%%3d.ts"
```

it generates .ts files like 1.ts 2.ts etc..

but if you are gonna to look to twitch.tv's m3u8 file it looks like this

```
#EXTM3U
#EXT-X-VERSION:3
#EXT-X-TARGETDURATION:3
#ID3-EQUIV-TDTG:2016-10-14T12:33:35
#EXT-X-MEDIA-SEQUENCE:345
#EXT-X-TWITCH-ELAPSED-SYSTEM-SECS:1368.979
#EXT-X-TWITCH-ELAPSED-SECS:1365.240
#EXT-X-TWITCH-TOTAL-SECS:1386.919
#EXTINF:3.440,
index-0000000346-Am9S.ts
#EXTINF:1.720,
index-0000000347-Am3j.ts
#EXTINF:3.980,
index-0000000348-MYfR.ts
#EXTINF:2.000,
index-0000000349-kIwd.ts
#EXTINF:3.300,
index-0000000350-TpwI.ts
#EXTINF:3.500,
index-0000000351-MAjv.ts
```

i want to do same is there any example ?
thanks.

best regards

Comment: ffmpeg can't do that. Question is: why would you want to do something like that?

Comment: Also can't help but notice most of your command line contradicts itself. E.g. you are supposedly reading mpeg-ts and writing mpeg-ts but there is a bitstream filter for mp4-to-mpegts conversion - why is it there? There are numerous options to handle video encoding but no transcoding actually happens. There is global_header flag which is not needed since muxer specifies this flag.

Comment: i want my .ts file names be unpredictable.they may create their own m3u8 file and still play my videos

Comment: well i prefer to dont edit command line too much for possibility of crash

Comment: Well, best you can do with stock ffmpeg is to use `use_localtime` option - that will make filenames less predictable. If you want something truly unpredictable you gonna have to modify ffmpeg or hire someone to do that for you.

Answer (score 0):

This can't be done directly with FFMPEG. Twitch processes the M3U8 file and rewrites it with their own custom format. Its touched on here in the very last paragraph: https://blog.twitch.tv/en/2017/10/10/live-video-transmuxing-transcoding-f-fmpeg-vs-twitch-transcoder-part-i-489c1c125f28/

> Certain information needs to be inserted into the HLS bitstreams to
> enhance the user experience on the player side. By building our own
> transcoder and player, Twitch can control the full end-to-end
> ingest-transcode-CDN-playback pipeline. This allows us to insert
> proprietary metadata structures into the transcoder output, which are
> eventually parsed by our player and utilized to produce effects unique
> to Twitch.